# Integrate the StartApp Ads in an Ionic Application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, startapp

Is there a way we can integrate the StartApp Ads on an Ionic 3 Application

StartApp: https://portal.startapp.com/#/download-sdk

The above link specifies that there is Cordova support

Is there a plugin already present to make use of to achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: No.. unfortunately